# Why did the Mathematica Language choose term rewriting instead of the Lambda Calculus as its basis?

Tags: lambda-calculus, history, mathematical-programming, term-rewriting, lisp

Now we can see that [Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church) [was associated with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Typed_lambda_calculi) the [Simply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) Typed [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typed_lambda_calculus). Indeed, it seems he explained the Simply Typed Lambda Calculus in order to reduce misunderstanding about the Lambda Calculus.

Now when John McCarthy created Lisp - he [based it on the Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCarthy_(computer_scientist)#Career_in_computer_science). This is by his own admission when he published ["Recursive functions of symbolic expressions and their computation by machine, Part I"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/367177.367199). You can [read it here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6096/AIM-008.pdf?sequence=2).

Now we know that at the core of [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is a [Lisp-like system](https://www.wolfram.com/language/faq/), but instead of being based purely on the Lambda Calculus, it is [based on a term-rewriting system](https://web.archive.org/web/20160707125523/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=8083007).

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160707125523/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=8083007) the author states state:

> Mathematica is fundamentally a term rewriting system... a more general concept than the Lambda Calculus behind Lisp.

My question is: **Why did the Mathematica Language choose term rewriting instead of the Lambda Calculus as its basis?**

Comment: I don't think this is ontopic here. You are asking about historical design decisions behind a proprietary piece of software, which is not a computer *science* question. Chances are nobody knows, or it was down to Wolfram's whims.

Comment: Note: I [asked in their chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30784837#30784837) if this would be welcome on [mathematica.SE]. If there is a positive answer, I'll migrate there.

Comment: They've changed their mind - they'd like to migrate it back...

Comment: [Here's the link to the M.SE version.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119933/why-did-the-mathematica-language-choose-term-rewriting-instead-of-the-lambda-cal)  There's an answer there.  @hawkeye Well, *crowds* don't have a single mind to change ...

Comment: \*throws arms in the air\* I don't know what we can do besides getting the okay of mods... but then, a mod expressed disagreement with the community votes, and the answer seems to be good; hope it helps you.

Comment: Surely this question can be generalised and made on-topic. For example, _What are possible motivations/trade-offs etc for designing a programming language based on term rewriting (e.g, Mathmatica) instead of the lambda calculus (e.g., Lisp)?_